# using neo4j bolt driver with nodejs

Tags: node.js, neo4j, neo4j-bolt

I have followed instruction on https://neo4j.com/developer/language-guides/ and successfully installed neo4j driver by npm command on windows operating system. but when I run the sample codes, I have got a following error :

```
module.js:538
throw err;
^
Error: Cannot find module 'neo4j-driver'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:536:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:466:25)
at Module.require (module.js:579:17)
at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (c:\NodejsEngine\Getstarted\addnodetoneo4j.js:2:16)
at Module._compile (module.js:635:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:646:10)
at Module.load (module.js:554:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:497:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:489:3)
```

Comment: Check in the project folder that the driver package is installed: `npm ls --depth=0`

Comment: Can you share more of your code?

Comment: And how you installed the driver.

Comment: Install neo4j driver by -- npm install neo4j-driver@1.5.0

Comment: and use your site sample :

Comment: const neo4j = require('neo4j-driver').v1;

const driver = neo4j.driver(uri, neo4j.auth.basic(user, password));
const session = driver.session();

const personName = 'Alice';
const resultPromise = session.run(
  'CREATE (a:Person {name: $name}) RETURN a',
  {name: personName}
);

resultPromise.then(result => {
  session.close();

  const singleRecord = result.records[0];
  const node = singleRecord.get(0);

  console.log(node.properties.name);

  // on application exit:
  driver.close();
});